# E:\ is not accessible. The request is not supported

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, permissions, external-hard-drive

Yesterday I installed Windows 10 Pro Anniversary Update (Version 1607 OS Build 14393.10) and my external disks no longer can be read.

When I attach them to the PC I get the following error message

```
Location is not available

E:\ is not accessible.

The request is not supported.
```

Disk Management utility shows disks are having RAW partitions only.

At the same time **I can read disks on other PC** with Windows 10 Pro Version 1511 OS Build 10586.494.

I can read those disk on my Smart TV too.

Both disks are NTFS formatted. Age, manufacturer and size are different.

What can be done to fix this? What might have cause the issue?

I tried to use [USB Oblivion tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usboblivion/) but it didn't help. I tried to check what access properties are set for the drives but there is no Security tab in the Properties dialog.

UPDATE:

I know I can copy my files using the other PC. This question is NOT about how to get data out of the disks.

I don't want to downgrade the Anniversary Update. I don't want to trash anything.

I am asking for how to make disks readable in my installation of Win 10 Anniversary update. And I would be happy to know what caused the issue in the first place.

UPDATE 2:

Both disks are in manufacturer's enclosures (not designed to be opened). One disk is Toshiba and another one is Western Digital. Both connect via USB 3.0 in my PC. I tried USB 2.0 too but that does not change anything.

Comment: For the time being, if you need the data from those drives, you can roll back the Anniversary Edition update (you only get ten days from the installation of the update to do that). My external drives still work, so I can't do any testing to see what might fix it, and you didn't say if it's OK to trash a drive for speculative testing. [How to downgrade Windows 10 Anniversary Update before its too late](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-downgrade-windows-10-anniversary-update-before-its-too-late-1574488).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Please see the edit.

Comment: Can you backup the data on one of your external drives so that I can suggest things to try which have the *possibility* of destroying the data on the drive?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Please suggest them now.

Comment: **You do this at your own risk.** Disconnect the external HDDs. Go to "Device Manager" (Windows key, start typing "hardware"). "View" menu -> "Show hidden devices". Expand the "Disk drives" node. Right-click on the drive corresponding to the external HDD. Choose "Uninstall". Repeat as necessary. Reboot. Connect external HDD.  Hope, but do not expect, the drive to work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the answer but it didn't help. Unistalled devices re-appeared and I got the same error message after the reboot and re-connection of one of the disks.

Comment: I had a little bit of hope for that. The next step, which may destroy your Windows 10, is to try install the Windows 10 motherboard drivers from the M/B manufacturer, if they are available. Then the Intel/AMD chipset drivers (if separate), which again may destroy Windows 10. [It is late here now, so I will not be back for some time.]

Comment: Is it in a USB enclosure?  What kind of enclosure is it?  What kind of drive?  How is it connected?

Comment: @WesSayeed Please see the update 2 to the question.

Comment: I've just read an article about Windows 10 Anniversary being a totally different OS and breaking drivers left and right. That seems to be the case here. You might just need to report the issue to Toshiba & WD and wait a couple of days for the good driver to be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE 2 (September 14th, 2016):

Some guys on Reddit say that KB3189866 update fixed the issue for them. At the same time some others say it didn't.

Mahesh (he is the authority on storage issues in Microsoft) [yesterday said](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vyifo/bug_windows_10_anniversary_update_tanked/d7l59nn)

> Folks, we are still working through all the issues reported. Believe
>   me, the team is working hard in getting the fix out to everyone's
>   machines. I request your continued patience during this time and
>   thanks for your help and support.

UPDATE:

Microsoft employee on Reddit confirmed this is an issue in Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

> We are actively building and testing an update to fix this issue into
>   Windows.  We’ll deploy the update via Windows Update as soon as that
>   process is finished, restoring access to your files on the affected
>   drives. In all of the cases that we have diagnosed, files were safely
>   intact on the drives – so please, don’t reformat.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

According to numerous discussions on Reddit and other forums the issue is widespread and most probably caused by changes introduced by the Anniversary Update. [The update changes driver signing rules](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/driver-signing-changes-windows-10).

This [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vyifo/bug_windows_10_anniversary_update_tanked/) is probably the most complete. and also shows how popular the issue is. There is also a Microsoft engineer (maheshrd) involved asking for assistance in reproducing and fixing the issue.

There are different "flavors" of the issue. Some relate to NTFS drives and other to FAT32 ones. Some can be fixed by reformatting of the drive and *some do not go away even after drive is reformatted*.

Given I have the latest drivers available for my hardware (and my hardware is not obscure in any way) and the fact none of the advices helped me I gave up and reverted to Windows 10 Pro Version 1511 OS Build 10586.494.

**And the issue is gone.**

It's really a pity to see such a bug making it into the Anniversary update. You never get a second chance to make a first impression, they say.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. Microsoft just released an update that solved the issue (at least for me!):

Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB3189866)

Just wondering how many people might have lost their data because of this error. Quite unbelievable!

EDIT: In case it is of any help, my hard drive was a Western Digital MyPassport Ultra 0820 USB 2TB.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared on WD My Passport disk formatted in NTFS. It came up after plugging my disk on my Smart TV. I connected an intenso older disk but I didn't have any problem afterwards. My disk is still readable on my TV.

I plug this information here, it may prove useful.